# if there is [1::] in dart?

Tags: algorithm, dart

In python we can write recursive function to count an element in a list like this:

```
def count(list):
if list == []:
return 0

return 1 + count(list[1::])
```

But if there is the method or something else to create this line of code  return 1 + count(list[1::]) in Dart?

I think, that we can do something like this using the dart collections like

```
var result = (1 + a.sum);
return result;
```

Now I try to solve this task like this:

```
void main() {
  List<int> n = [2, 6, 7]; //the arrays of element

  int sumsReccur(List<int> n) {
    if (n.length <= 0) {
      return 0; //base case
    }
  }

  var result = 1 + sumsReccur(n.length);

  return result;
}
```

Comment: It is not an efficient solution to do this since you would allocate a new list for each iteration where this list contains all elements from the previous list with the exception of one element. If you want to get the sum of all elements in the list, there are better ways to do that with: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/Iterable/reduce.html or https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/Iterable/fold.html

Comment: I'm not a Dart person but it seems you are missing to remove elements from the array.

Comment: Alternative, you can change the code so it forwards the original list and an index parameter which tells what element we should start from. That would be more efficient since we then don't need to do any additional list allocations.

Comment: Note that the talk about inefficiency isn't specific to Dart; it'd be inefficient for Python too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart has lazy iterables, which is more likely to be what you want.
The way to do `iterable[1::]` is `iterable.skip(1)`.

It's still horribly inefficient, but you can do:

```dart
  int count(Iterable values) {
    if (values.isEmpty) return 0;
    return 1 + count(values.skip(1));
  }
```

It's still going to take O(n^2) time to count the number of elements of `values`, but since it's lazy, it won't copy the *elements* too, so it only does O(n) memory allocation.

In practice, never do this if you care about performance.
It's better to iterate on the *iterator*:

```dart
int count(Iterable values) {
  int countIterator(Iterator iterator) {
    if (iterator.moveNext()) return 1 + countIterator(iterator);
    return 0;
  }
  return countIterator(values.iterator);
}
```

Again, the recursion here is trivial, and recursing on an iterator is usually a bad idea (better to have a loop, because there *are* limits to the recursion stack size, and you have no control over the depth of the recursion this way.)

When dealing with lists or iterables, the preferred way to access them is by iterating in a loop (`for (var v in values) ...` or `for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) ... list[i] ...`), or with a helper function like `values.forEach((value) { doSomething(value); });`.

All you're calculating her is `values.length` anyway, so it's not hard to do better than recursion.

Comment: thanks for such a detailed answer. My task is to write a recursive function for counting an element, and when I started solving this task, I immediately thought that it would probably be nice to use a loop for this, but since the task indicates that it is recursion that needs to be done, I I didn't understand exactly how to do it. Thanks again. Also thanks to everyone who pointed out the necessary methods for calculating sum of values in the array

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`sublist` method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/List/sublist.html):

```
int sumsReccur(List<int> n) {
  if (n.length <= 0) {
    return 0; //base case
  }
  return subReccur(n.sublist(1));
}
```